# Caliburn Micro ViewLocator with different namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, namespaces, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro for MVVM. Now I have the following situation. I have a UserControl with View and ViewModel in my first assembly `assembly1` in `namespace1`. If I use it in an  second assembly `assembly2` that has the same namespace `namespace1` (it´s in the same solution) everything works fine.

Now I'd like to use my ViewModel in another `Solution` with namespace `namespace3`. If I try this I always get the error, that View couldn't be located.

I build up a workaround that sets the Binding manually in the bootstrapper (using Ninject).

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    _kernel = new StandardKernel();
    _kernel.Bind<OverlayManagerView>().To<OverlayManagerView>().InSingletonScope();
    _kernel.Bind<OverlayManagerViewModel>().To<OverlayManagerViewModel>().InSingletonScope();
    base.Configure();
}

protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModelBinder.Bind(IoC.Get<OverlayManagerViewModel>(), IoC.Get<OverlayManagerView>(), null);
...
}
```

This is working, but if I'd like to use my ViewModels from `assembly1` I won't always set the Binding manually and as Singleton.

Is there a way to tell the `Caliburn ViewLocator` that Views might be at a different namespace?

I tried following not working...

```
        ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("namespace1", "namespace3");
        ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("namespace1", "namespace1");
        ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("namespace3", "namespace1");
```

Maybe someone knows a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Configure`method you should use :

```
ViewLocator.AddSubNamespaceMapping("ViewModelsNamespace", "ViewsNamespace");
```

and you have to override the following method :

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {

        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        assemblies.AddRange(base.SelectAssemblies());
        //Load new ViewModels here
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        assemblies.AddRange(from fileName in fileEntries
                            where fileName.Contains("ViewModels.dll")
                            select Assembly.LoadFile(fileName));
        assemblies.AddRange(from fileName in fileEntries
                            where fileName.Contains("Views.dll")
                            select Assembly.LoadFile(fileName));
        return assemblies;


    }
```

in order to let Caliburn know about your new dlls.